# Best way to trim value in textbox before save/insert using formview into datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, trim, formview

By triming i mean something like.

First name "John      " -> trim to "John"

Last name  "Lennon  " -> trim to "Lennon"

I have those Textbox in FormView, binding with property using Bind("FirstName").

The FormView bind with Entity Datasource.

I want those value to be trim before saving, what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: `TextBox.Text().Trim()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx#Y0 ?

Comment: use too much labor to type this one by one, any faster solution ?

Comment: Seriously? Turn it into a helper/extension method and pass in the value. I can't see how trimming 2 strings is too much 'labor' (sic)

Comment: When there are about 10-15 textbox in a lot of page it will be a lot of labors.

Comment: Computers are generally excellent at repeating tasks multiple times, be it 10, 15, or 1,478,239,129 times - I think the idea I'm sharing is for acting on a single instance of your problem, it's *your* perogative to work out how to modularise it. I'm not advocating that you write a `Trim()` command for every single thing you bind to a model from your datasource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
formView.Controls
    .OfType<System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t => t.Text = t.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: Maybe put it in a utilities class (that's what I did) just in case the logic needs to change.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
TextBox.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`string.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method is what you want.

Comment: use too much labor to type this one by one, any faster solution ?

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu You've spent time typing a question about it on SO. I'm sure you can type the word `Trim` a few times.

Comment: When there are about 10-15 textbox in a lot of page it will be a lot of labors.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Textbox text with trimmed one. Then write code that to save it in database from Textbox text. This way your text in UI and backend will be same and corrected.

```
mytextbox.Text = mytextbox.Text.Trim();

//save textbox text in database
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Trim() //for triming
```

For saving the labor, what you can do is to create a helper method, and intercept it before any binding set.

I had once such similar scenario, where i need to log every SQL query (ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery) with parameters.

What i simply did was to create a static method excepting IDBCommand. Then logged all the parameters in it. After that called the executed.

Example

```
public static CommandIntercepter 
{
  void ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand command)
  {
   ...//logged all parameters
   command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  }
 }
```

Now I had replaced command.ExecuteNonQuery, with CommandIntercepter.ExecuteNonQuery(command) through the code.

This way, i was saved from logging individual query parameters at different code points.

If you have such intercepting point inside Bind(String propertyName), you can do trimming there. Or You can create TrimBind function, and call TrimBind instead of Bind

```
void TrimBind(String propertyName)
{
  ...//do trimming
  Bind(propertyName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two text boxes you can use

```
string firstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
string lastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
```

If you don't know how many textboxes are going to use or there are many textboxes and you want to trim them all , even for multiple pages , I prefer to create Extended Property for TextBox and override its Text property to return always trimmed value.

Answer (score 0):

you can also trim your data before sending to any data-source by using `OnItemInserting` or `OnItemUpdating` events

```
protected void ItemInsetring(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        FormView fv = sender as FormView;
        foreach (FormViewRow r in fv.Controls[0].Controls)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in r.Controls)
            {
                foreach (TextBox txtin cell.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    txt.Text = txt.Text.Trim();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
private void TrimTextBoxes(DependencyObject depObject)
{
    if (depObject is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox txt = depObject as TextBox;
        txt.Text = txt.Text.Trim();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObject); i++)
    {
        TrimTextBoxes(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObject, i));
    }
}
```

This will iterate trough all your controls. You have to name your main grid, in this case, `<Grid x:Name="Grid1">`, then on your code behind, you call the method

```
TrimTextBoxes(this.Grid1);
```

This will trim all your textboxes within your main grid.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Appreciating all the answer.. I come up with this finally.

Trimimg on Formview

```
    protected void frmSubScription_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate("signUp");

        if (Page.IsValid == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        // trimimg value
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Values.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Values[i] = e.Values[i].ToString().Trim();
        }         
    }
```

Trimiming on GridView

```
    protected void gdvSubscribers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // trimimg value
        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewValues.Count; i++)
        {
            if (e.NewValues[i] is string)
            {
                e.NewValues[i] = e.NewValues[i].ToString().Trim();
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string PersonName
{
  get { return txtPersonName.Text.Trim(' '); }
  set { txtPersonName.Text = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Public Sub TrimText()
      Dim _allTxt As New List(Of Control)
      'get all controls (recursive)
      _allTxt = GetAllControls(_allTxt, Me, GetType(TextBox))
      For Each _txt As TextBox In _allTxt
         AddHandler _txt.Enter, AddressOf TextBox_Enter ' Event to fire on enter (or ...)
      Next
   End Sub

   Public Shared Function GetAllControls(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of Control)
      If parent Is Nothing Then Return list
      If parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
         list.Add(parent)
      End If
      For Each _child As Control In parent.Controls
         GetAllControls(list, _child, ctrlType)
      Next
      Return list
   End Function

   Private Sub TextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      Dim _txt As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
      _txt.Text = _txt.Text.Trim()
   End Sub
```